# Array multiplication in Objective-C, for NSArray and NSMutableArray

Tags: arrays, objective-c, nsmutablearray

In Python, the expression `2*[a,b,c]` (with a,b,c variables) is meaningful, and returns `[a,b,c,a,b,c]`. Also, in Python, lists (or arrays) are mutable by design.

It is easy enough to write a category on e.g. `NSArray` that implements an instance method `-(NSArray*) multiplyByNumber:(NSInteger)number;` which copies Python's behavior.
But the mutability is not given in Objective-C: `NSArray`s are immutable by design, but they have a mutable subclass `NSMutableArray`, which can not really inherit the `multiplyByNumber` method.

Is there a way to avoid reimplementation of the method for `NSMutableArray`? Or do I really have to do it for the mutable subclasses as well?

Comment: You should add `-[NSArray arrayByMultiplyingByNumber:]` and `-[NSMutableArray multiplyByNumber:]`, like `arrayByAddingObject:` and `addObject:`. `NSMutableArray` inherits `arrayByMultiplyingByNumber:`.

Comment: Oh, and I'd just call the super and then do a mutable copy. And this is.. "safe", for lack of a better word, because the name `arrayByMultiplyingByNumber` suggests the return value is not mutable. Thank you!

Comment: No, `-[NSMutableArray  arrayByMultiplyingByNumber :]` is not implemented, it returns a `NSArray`. `-[NSMutableArray multiplyByNumber:]` is `- (void) multiplyByNumber:(NSInteger)number`, it mutates the receiver.

Comment: Ah yeah. I changed my approach, so I won't be needing this anymore, but I couldn't implement `multiplyByNumber` on `NSMutableArray` calls to super's `arrayByMultiplyingByNumber`: how do you "overwrite" self?

Comment: The obvious approach would be a completely separate implementation from what super offers (adding the array to itself number-1 times), but I would have liked to do it differently

Comment: `arrayByMultiplyingByNumber:` and `multiplyByNumber:` can both call the same function or private method. Or `arrayByMultiplyingByNumber:` can do `mutableCopy`, `multiplyByNumber:` and return an immutable copy.